# How high does light pollution reach into the sky?

Tags: light, light-pollution

I want to know how high does light pollution typically reach into the sky **straight up**? Has anyone ever researched this because I wonder if being at 10000ft elevation would reduce the amount of light pollution from nearby cities because of the height assuming that light pollution weakens the higher you go. How high would it go **straight up** the sky (*not* to the sides about how far I would have to travel to have no light pollution disturbing the night sky)?

Comment: This is a little interesting, it sounds plausible that there exists an altitude where the amount of reflective particles is negligible. There may however be huge local variations.

Answer (score 5):

Light pollution occurs because light from the ground refects off atoms in the atmosphere. So you can reduce light pollution either by getting away from  light, or getting above the atmosphere. 50% of the atmosphere lies below 5500m,  if you can get 5500 m high, you half light pollution.  Getting high also improves clarity, and reduces the disturbance caused by atmospheric turbulence, which is why most major telescopes are situated on mountain tops.

Comment: also see answers to [Why (actually) is the night sky so bright in the city? How far up is that happening?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/8795/6031) in Earth Science SE and references therein